# Can I get a squared image from a ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent

Tags: android, android-camera

By default the image I can get after the camera app is done it will be rectangular. I wonder if it is possible to get the camera app to get square image without having to crop the original rectangular image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry.

First, there is no documented option for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` that offers this.

Second, there are thousands of device models, shipping with hundreds of camera apps pre-installed. Other camera apps can be installed by users. Any of those could handle your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request. None of those cameras have to offer square pictures at all, let alone by request from a third-party app.

Comment: I was fearing that would be the answer but thanks for the response.